# How to add step filter[For debugging] to katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

How to add some classes to "Step Filter" feature of katalon studio, so that while debugging, control won't take to those classes defined in step filter feature.

Whenever i am calling a custom keyword method, katalon is not taking me to that specific file.If i put a debug point in that method of custom keyword file, control will stop over there.

I remember adding something like that in eclipse. Does Katalon provides any feature like that?

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Found the answer.

It is under "Katalon Studio Preferrances".